# Rails query has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three `models` associated with the following ways:

#### User model

```rb
has_many :project_memberships
has_many :projects, through: :project_memberships
```

#### Project model

```rb
has_many :project_memberships
has_many :users, through: :project_memberships
```

#### Project membership model

```rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
```

The `project membership` model also has additional fields like `user_role`, `invitation_accepted` etc.
I want to get all the `users` in a specified `project`, with all the `project membership` fields.

Example:

```json
# user json response
[
 {
   id: user_id,
   name: user_name,
   user_role: "admin",
   invitation_accepted: true
 },
 {
   // Etc
 }
]
```

Currently, I have something like:

```rb
def index
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @team_members = @project.project_memberships
end
```

The `team_members` only returns

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProjectMembership id: "42087cd2-31f5-4453-b620-5b47a82de422", user_id: "4f428880-48d0-40d0-b6d6-eed9172ce78d", project_id: "3e758d26-7625-4cbd-8980-77085f8d38a0", role: "admin", invitation_accepted: true, job_title: nil, created_at: "2020-10-24 05:48:38", updated_at: "2020-10-24 05:48:38">]>
```

I am getting the `user_id`, but don't know how to merge the actual `user` fields in the above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [includes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) to preload data (behind the scenes, it is performing a join).

```
@team_members = @project.project_memberships.includes(:user)
```

Now you can call `@team_members[0].user.name` (or extract the user name from all of them) and it doesn't fire an additional database query to load the user.

Note that this does work without `includes`, but it will be slower, and introduces a common pitfall known as "N+1 queries"